# How to use PMD with sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd

Hello I am new with Sonarqube and I want to add PMD and checkstyle to my sonarqube. How to do that?

I have created new custom quality profile in sonarqube and after that selected pmd and check-style but in that rules column.

It is showing 0 rule so when I am built project its no showing anything except success.
so I don't know where I am making a mistake.
I have downloaded plugins for both but they're not working.
I am uploading wrong pmd check-style files or anything else?

Image showing file to be uploaded but which file should I upload?
.xml file ?

Comment: Using following files
sonarqube 5.1.1
pmd plugin 2.4.1
checkstyle plugin 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You say you've installed the SonarQube PMD and Checkstyle plugins. Good.

You also mention that you've created a new custom quality profile. You'll need to either set it to be the default profile or [specifically assign your project](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Non-rule+Profile+Edits+and+Information) to use it during analysis.

Your question seems to hint that you'd like to upload pre-run reports from Checkstyle and PMD. Reuse reports mode is not available for either of those tools. Instead, you'll need to [activate the relevant rules in your Quality Profile](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules) and run an analysis.